# the same code (for carousel - bootstrap) on VSCode dosent work but works on codeply.com

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

code:

```
      <div class = "carousel-inner">
        <div class = "carousel-item active" style = "background-color:red" >
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <div id="testimonials-img-plus-text">
          <img src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "carousel-item " style = "background-color:blue">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <div id="testimonials-img-plus-text">
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class = "carousel-control-next carousel-control-next-icon" data-bs-target = "#t-carousel"></button>
      <button class = "carousel-control-prev carousel-control-prev-icon" data-target = "#t-carousel"></button>
    </div>
```

this code works on codeply.com but dosent work in VS Code (by working, i mean the carousel dosent scroll by itself unlike in codeply)[image]

**codeply refercence: https://www.codeply.com/p/eCBm9Ho9rx**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure u have added the css and js files of **bootstrap latest version (5.2)** .

If you want to add it locally, just download bootstrap from [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v5.2.0.zip)

**or you can also add using cdn like below..**

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thanks! i wasnt using the js cdn link